# How to know if a field of form is edited or not ? Is there any method in java ? The UI is built with vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

How to know if a field of the form is edited or not? Is there any method in java? The UI is built with vaadin.
I want to throw an error if a field is not edited, I can throw error I just want an answer how can we check if the field is edited or not using java?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a form and use `Binder` to bind the fields with the bean, there is a mechanism in `Binder` that is tracking this and you can use `Binder#hasChanges()` method to check there is one or more field in the form that has pending changes.

In case your use case is actually to verify that a mandatory field has been entered, you should use `asRequired(..)` validator to validate that the input is not null / not empty.

If your bean has non-null / non-empty default value, which should be altered, you can use validator that checks the input value is not the default value.

Comment: Can you give code snippet or something ?

Comment: The full documentation is here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder